# Unexpected T_ELSE on line 9

Tags: php, session

**Snippet of my php file**

```
session_start(); // Bring in old sessionID
$sess_id = session_id(); // assign old session variable to $sess_id var

if(empty($sess_id)){    # If no sessionID redirect back home.
    header('Location: ../index.php');
}

else(!empty($sess_id)){
```

**Line 9 in the file:** 
  `else(!empty($sess_id)){`

Why is this throwing this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an `echo` between the `if` and the `else`. Take it out.

```
if(empty($sess_id)) {    # If no sessionID redirect back home.
    header('Location: ../index.php');
} else {
```

Comment: Also, else{  or elseif(!empty($sess_id)) {, but else{ is better

Comment: @AndrewLeap: Thanks, missed that :P

Comment: @CodeTalk: Try again, I edited my answer. If you need a condition with an `else`, you need to use `elseif` - but as Andrew Leap pointed out, you don't even need the condition.

Comment: Dont need what condition? And why

Answer (score 2):

You can't have anything between the if and the else of a statement:

```
if ($condition) {
    doSomething();
}
// Nothing can go here!
else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start(); // Bring in old sessionID
$sess_id = session_id(); // assign old session variable to $sess_id var

if(empty($sess_id)){    # If no sessionID redirect back home.
    header('Location: ../index.php');
}

else(!empty($sess_id)){
```

change it to

```
else if(!empty($sess_id)){
```

Simple fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Or use several if statements with die() like:

```
session_start(); // Bring in old sessionID
$sess_id = session_id(); // assign old session variable to $sess_id var

if(empty($sess_id)){    # If no sessionID redirect back home.
    die(header('Location: ../index.php')); #Stop script and go to ../index.php
}

if(!empty($sess_id)){
....
die('some.php');
}

....other statements.....
```